# Swift SQLite I/O error

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, io, swift3

I keep getting the following error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: disk I/O
>   error (code: 10): file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 178

when I implement the following code:

```
try db!.transaction() {
    hold = true
    for obj in object {
        if table.rawValue == DBTableNames.Products.rawValue {
            let product : ProductObject =  obj as! ProductObject
            insert = self.productsTable.insert(
                self.productcode <- product.productcode,
                self.admincost <- product.admincost,
                self.allocatedstock <- product.allocatedstock,
                self.availablestock <- product.availablestock,
                self.backorderstock <- product.backorderstock,
                self.barcode <- product.barcode,
                self.binno <- product.binno,
                self.casesperlayer <- product.casesperlayer,
                self.clearanceprice <- product.clearanceprice,
                self.exportprice <- product.exportprice,
                self.fulldescription <- product.fulldescription,
                self.gqcoded <- product.gqcoded,
                self.group <- product.group,
                self.innerbarcode <- product.innerbarcode,
                self.innerqty <- product.innerqty,
                self.lastPoDate <- product.lastPoDate as Date,
                self.layersperpallet <- product.layersperpallet,
                self.longdescription1 <- product.longdescription1,
                self.mtdsales <- product.mtdsales,
                self.onorderstock <- product.onorderstock,
                self.outerbarcode <- product.outerbarcode,
                self.packqty <- product.packqty,
                self.palletqty <- product.palletqty,
                self.physicalstock <- product.physicalstock,
                self.rollingsales <- product.rollingsales,
                self.rsp <- product.rsp,
                self.shortdescription <- product.shortdescription,
                self.threemonth <- product.threemonth,
                self.warehouse <- product.warehouse,
                self.weight <- product.weight,
                self.wholesaleprice <- product.wholesaleprice,
                self.ytdsales <- product.wholesaleprice)
        }
    }
    try self.db!.run(insert)
}
```

I understand its an I/O error but I don't understand what else could be accessing the database blocking the insert

I'm using the following fw:https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: hey. Did you find any solution to this problem? I faced the same problem but it happened sometimes is unknown cases :S

Comment: I just ran into this problem as well. Did anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting the error on a simulator, please read part 2. Try part 1 if the error happens on an actual device, but also try running your app in a simulator and try part 2 of my answer.

1. If you are using actual device and get the SQLite I/O error:
   The reason for the error might be the location of the database file. The location was:

   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/someid/Documents/somedb.sqlite3

and I got rid of the error by moving the db file to:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/someid/Library/somedb.sqlite3
```

So instead of:

```
static var destinationSqliteURL: URL!
let myPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
destinationSqliteURL = myPath.appendingPathComponent("somedb.sqlite3")
```

I used:

```
static var destinationSqliteURL: URL!
let myPath = fileManager.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask)[0]
destinationSqliteURL = myPath.appendingPathComponent("somedb.sqlite3")
```

2. If you are using the simulator and get the SQLite I/O error:

you should verify the file is ok (using xcode simulator), by printing out myPath and cd into the folder containing the database, then in terminal open the database file with:

sqlite3 somedb.sqlite3

Probably there is no file there or it is corrupted and has to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. My solution was to remove the db reference from my (singleton) manager class and reinitialise it after downloading a new database version. My manager kept the reference for the old database.